90s TV Show about a man has all is family/friends no longer recognizing him
A while back, I think in the 90s, I remember watching a TV Show where the main character was left all alone, in the sense that (the people he believed to be) his family and friends would no longer recognize him.
This show was American. It was spoken in English.
I remember a few scenes: 
The main character would find a woman he knew (or at least he thought he knew) in some parking lot. He went to her, hoping/expecting she would recognize him. She didn't. He would argue with her asking why she was pretending they did not know each other. I believe at some point the cops would come over and the woman showed her identity card with a different name than the one the main character expected.
I never saw the full series, so I don't remember if indeed some kinda of organization made all his family/friends forget him (by paying them I suppose) of if he was delusional.
Can't remember the name of the main character neither. I hope still information will be enough for someone to remember it.

Maybe Nowhere Man?

Nowhere Man is the story of photojournalist Thomas Veil, who discovers that his life has been abruptly "erased": his friends claim not to know him, his wife claims not to recognize him and is living with another man. His ATM cards and credit cards no longer work. His best friend turns up dead. His mother, recovering from a stroke, is incapable of confirming his existence. In the course of a single evening, every trace of Tom's identity is gone.
Tom believes this is a conspiracy related to a photograph he took a year earlier, depicting four men being hanged in South America by what appear to be US soldiers. The only evidence Tom has of his past are the negatives of that photograph. A mysterious organization covertly pursues Tom in search of the negatives. The series revolves around Veil's attempts to get his life back by trying to find out more about the organization, while also trying to keep the negative safe.
In the final episode, "Gemini," it is revealed that Tom had been captured by the organization prior to the events of the series' first episode, and that all his memories of his life, including his marriage and even his name, had been implanted as part of a brainwashing experiment known as Project Marathon. He learns that he is actually a covert government operative codenamed "Gemini", and is part of a secret task force called "Heritage House" which was formed to investigate the organization and Project Marathon. He also learns that his copy of the "Hidden Agenda" photograph, as well as his memories of having taken it, have been altered, and that the original negative shows that the four men being lynched are actually U.S. senators being murdered by the organization.
In the final episode, Tom questions the "number two man at the FBI" at gunpoint, but the man kills himself rather than risk revealing information under torture. The series ends with Tom watching a videotape that had been in the FBI man's possession, a film that finally explains everything. We see "Tom" sitting in a chair under the influence being brainwashed into believing he's "Thomas Veil" and the life he's been living. We hear he works for the FBI and this is all a training exercise.

